# Pyspark throwing task failure error while initializing new column with UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have this spark dataframe:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+------+
|                 qid|       question_text|target|
+--------------------+--------------------+------+
|403d7d49a9713e6f7caa|Do coconut trees ...|     0|
|edc9a2709785501cce09|What are 5 must-r...|     0|
|c912510d490de9e8c55c|How can I make my...|     0|
|bcd2395ccebea4d57604|Is reading biogra...|     0|
|d26dcd0879465c08ace5|Is the reason why...|     1|
|1c6398530de0b31e985a|Does John McCain ...|     1|
|69c68408690e66889e6a|Isn't the time th...|     1|
|d1a7d8a1da31041048a6|Why do people eat...|     0|
|54e96f880709e3cf9dd7|How do I get the ...|     0|
|f89c04a1c61487623ba9|What does the kno...|     0|
+--------------------+--------------------+------+
```

I am trying to apply this UDF:

```
def check_all_spelling_correct(sentence):
  
  doc=nlp(sentence)
  spell_check_performed=0
  if doc._.performed_spellCheck==True:
    spell_check_performed=1
  return spell_check_performed
```

Using :

```
check_all_spelling_correct_UDF = udf(lambda x:check_all_spelling_correct(x),IntegerType())
df_sub_2=df_sub.withColumn("Is spelling correct", check_all_spelling_correct_UDF(col("question_text")))
df_sub_2.collect()
```

But I am getting this error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o235.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 100.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 100.0 (TID 1441) (DESKTOP-2TQTOQ2 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(EvalPythonExec.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:863)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:863)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:189)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:175)
... 24 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2279)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:394)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:338)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:366)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:338)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToPython$1(Dataset.scala:3538)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3706)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3704)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3535)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:81)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec.$anonfun$doExecute$2(EvalPythonExec.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:863)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:863)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:189)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:175)
... 24 more

Answer (score 0):

`df_sub_2.collect()` will bring all the data to the driver node and when working with large datasets, it is very costly operation that results in stage failure.

Instead of `df.collect()` , use `df.take(10)` to see the first ten rows of the output dataframe.

OR if you only want to use `df.collect()` then you can increase the spark.driver.maxResultSize (default 1G) property like this and then use `df.collect()` :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local[*]') \
    .appName('StackOverflow') \
    .config('spark.dirver.maxResultSize', '4096') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Tried both. Same error. I am using a Dataframe with 10 rows.